# How to create a python program that run calling name instead of name.py from root terminal?

Tags: python

If I have a `main.py` file in a folder, how can I create a command in my PC that, calling only main from any point in the terminal, makes my `main.py` file running? Thanks

Comment: On windows, linux or macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add main.py to your PATH. What happens when you are running, for instance, `python` is that your terminal looks up the command `python` in PATH and runs the program that it is pointing to. You could see it as a kind of shortcut to the program Python.

By adding your program to your PATH, you can tell the computer that if you type `helloworld` in your terminal, the terminal should run `/my/path/to/helloworld.py`.

I don't know what OS you are on, so here are links for most common OS on how to add a PATH variable.

[Windows](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

[Linux](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-directory-to-path-in-linux/)

[Mac OSX](https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux or Mac OS X, make sure the program has a valid shebang line such as `#! /usr/bin/python` that points to the Python executable you want to run the script with, then enter `chmod +x main.py`.  Finally, rename the script to remove the `.py` extension.

You can now invoke it (if you're in the same directory) with `./main`. If you want to be able to invoke regardless of the directory you're in, add the script's directory to your `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

**Setting the path and variables in Windows 10**

1. Press the Windows key+X to access the Power User Task Menu. In the
   Power User Task Menu, select the System option. In the About window,
   click the Advanced system settings link under Related settings on
   the    far-right side.
2. In the System Properties window, click the Advanced    tab, then
   Click the Environment Variables button near the bottom of    that
   tab.
3. In the Environment Variables window (pictured below),
   highlight the Path variable in the System variables section and
   click    the Edit button.
4. Add or modify the path lines with the paths you want    the computer
   to access. Each directory path is separated with a    semicolon, as
   shown below.

   C:...\main.py